# Shadowbox - 360 Image Slider

Tags: jquery

Hi i'm trying to combine Shadowbox to open up a 360 image slider. This is the method I've tried, opening an inline element.

```
 <a href="#threesixty" rel="shadowbox">test</a>
 <div id="threesixty">
 <div id="spinner">
 <span>0%</span>
 </div>
 <ol id="threesixty_images"></ol>
 </div>
```

Obviously it doesn't work wondering if anyone has any tips, I can get shadowbox to work with everything else so it's just this I'm having trouble with.

I managed to get the 360 image slider to open in Shadowbox a while back but can't remember how I did it sadly :<

Many Thanks

Arthur.

Comment: Found a solution, probably not the best way of doing it but it works in case anyone has the same question.

Comment: rather than include the solution in the question, take it out and answer your own question and accept it. That way it's clearer to everyone what the question and answer is.